# How to find a column value based on the unique value for another column

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Class     Value
A         5.4
A         5.4
A         5.4
B         3.6
B         2.7
C         4.02
C         4.02
C         4.02
D         6.33
D         6.33
```

What I want is to retrieve only the classes that have similar values, which in this case should return the class `A` and `D` but not, for example, the class `B` since it has two different values.

To do that, I tried the following:

```
sub <- dataset[as.logical(ave(dataset$Value, dataset$Class, FUN = function(x) all(x==x))), ]
```

But this returns all the classes which I don't want.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `aggregate` with number of `unique` (`length(unique)`)

```
filterdf=aggregate(Value ~ Class, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
df[df$Class%in%filterdf[filterdf$Value==1,]$Class,]
   Class Value
1      A  5.40
2      A  5.40
3      A  5.40
6      C  4.02
7      C  4.02
8      C  4.02
9      D  6.33
10     D  6.33
```

Alternative from markus

```
idx <- with(df, ave(Value, Class, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1)
df[idx, ]
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar solution using `ave` which you might want to add as alternative. `idx <- with(df, ave(Value, Class, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1); df[idx, ]`

Comment: @markus that is great thank you :-) , if you would like convert it as an answer I will definitively upvote for you man

Comment: That is kind of you. I found it too similiar to what you posted 1 minute earlier. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Class) %>%
 filter(all(Value == first(Value)))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Class) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(Value) == 1)
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Class) %>%
 filter(all(Value %/% first(Value) != 0))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Class, Value) %>%
 mutate(temp = seq_along(Value)) %>%
 group_by(Class) %>%
 filter(sum(temp[temp == 1]) == 1) %>%
 select(-temp)
```

Or basically the same as the post from @W-B:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Class) %>%
 filter(length(unique(Value)) == 1)
```